# cross-validation

Tags: algorithm, svm

ist it possible to do a  10-fold cross-validation with svmmulticlass or do I have to implement this manually?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't really understand why this question has gotten two close votes and a downvote; Support Vector Machines are inherently a programming-related topic, and although I don't know the answer to the question I do understand what is being asked.  It's not off-topic at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little searching on [Google](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=svm+multiclass+cross+validation&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) and came across [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.114.4532&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which talks about k-fold cross validation using multiclass support vector machines.  You might look there and perhaps look at both the references as well as other papers that reference it if you don't get an answer in the paper I cited.